# Does sql server calculate views every time when someone query the views?

Tags: sql-server, view

I wonder whether sql server calculate views every time when someone query the views. It is because **everytime** I query the views, it take such a long time.

And when I tried to shorten the time by selecting only top 10 rows from the view, it takes the same amount of time. I suspect sql server need to calculate the view for the whole table even if I only want a few rows from the view, am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a view is just a macro (unless indexed). The behaviour is well known.

See [Tony Rogerson's article](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/01/03/views-they-offer-no-optimisation-benefits-they-are-simply-inline-macros-use-sparingly.aspx). You can see it yourself in the query plans too. The view doesn't exist on the query plan because it *can't* exist as a macro

Also note the ["Predicate Pushing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653979/why-does-putting-a-where-clause-outside-view-have-terrible-performance/6654525#6654525) phenomenon when you filter or TOP on views